What you see are (9), what's hinted is (4)
Your task is to place a number of "?'s" in the last (4th) row. Explain your reasoning.
 [1]   {2}  4   4   
1{0}1 4 5 6  (3)  6 7 *8*
 (1)    2   4   4


 ????????
 ???????? 
 ??????????????


The number of ?s

 are 11!

Why?

 The diagram above represents the four mathematical operators from left to right: addition, division, multiplication and subtraction

Because

 If you connect the adjacent numbers (of a difference of 1) on each of the parts with of the diagram with straight lines you get their symbols:
 

Also

 The first three are also hinted at by the number of ?s (representing their letters) in the section below in that same order. Leaving only subtraction (an 11 letter word)  behind.

As for the brackets:

 if we combine the numbers contained in the same kind of brackets we get 13, 1, 20, 8 and converting these letters using the A1Z26 cipher we get MATH.

The title

 Refers to the hint (MATH) as opposed to the (OPERATORS) the actual theme of the puzzle.


Well done! The brackets/stars give you a (4)-letter word.  Vs lbh zngpu fnzr flzobyf, naq pbaireg gb yrggref.This is the hint I refered to in the title. And what you see are the four mathematical (9).

If you anagram the numbers they spell Zngu

Ok I think this answer now covers everything
